# How to use Java to start a bat file on windows and sh file on linux to run from a specific directory

Tags: java, linux, bash, batch-file

I am trying to make a program which will execute a bat file when run on windows and a sh file when run on linux, but I need the bash/sh file to start running from a specific directory.

For example:
My program is located at `C:\Program\test.jar`
My bash file is located at `C:\File\start.bat`
I want to make the java runnable execute the `start.bat` file from its folder and not `test.jar` running directory.

I tried using `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /C start \"\" \"C:\File\start.bat"");` and it works, but it runs the bat file from `C:\Program\test.jar`, and for what the bat file does, I need it to run from `C:\File\start.bat`.

I also need to do the same for Linux, so I am asking here because after the bat issue is fixed, this issue will likely stomp me as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`ProcessBuilder`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html) and set the working directory with [`ProcessBuilder::directory`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html#directory-java.io.File-)